# Depth First Search - Advantages of traversing random neighbours

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Depth First Search allows to traverse adjacent vertices in an arbitrary order.
Are there any advantages in choosing random neighbours vs choosing neighbours in ascending fashion?

Consider the exploration order of following graph:

[image: Sample graph]

```
0 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 ..
0 -> 1 -> 8 -> 7 ..
```

**Can random choice lead to more favourable results?**

Comment: How would do you define "more favorable"? What is the metric you are using? Otherwise, the answer is "it depends"...

Comment: Space is constant. Time can be considered @tucuxi

Comment: In ascending what ? Node label ? Why would this have any signifiance ?

Comment: Should all the edges be directed (have arrowheads?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I find a situation in which there is an advantage?

Yes.  Easily.  If I have a connected graph, traversing with random choices is guaranteed to eventually reach every node.  Traversing in order is guaranteed to eventually wind up in a loop.

Is there an advantage in general?

No.  For example in the connected example, a simple "keep track of where we have been" makes both reach everything.  Which one will find a target node first will be a question of chance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the DFS is not responsible for the arbitrary order.

The way of traversing the nodes depend on 2 things:

1. The order in which you pushed the adjacent nodes in the adjacency list (Generally influenced by the order of the edges provided in the input).
2. The custom order which you decide for traversal (as you mentioned, the sorted order).

**Answer to your question:**

1. Choosing the order in which you pushed the adjacent nodes in the adjacency list does not affect the complexity.
2. If you decide to traverse adjacent nodes in sorted, then you need to maintain the adjacency list accordingly, which comes at the cost of extra factor of V*log(V).

Overall time complexity = O(V+E) + O(V * log(V)).

O(V+E) => for DFS.

O(V * log(V)) => for priority queue/sorting the adjacency list.

Here, `V` = number of nodes in the graph and `E` = number of edges.